# Wordpress Plugin Jpagination Integration Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have some problems integrating this plugin to my loop
I do not understand the methodology of pagination..

I did not have problems OWL carrousel, but this I do not get it.

```
    <script>
                $(function(){

  $("div.holder").jPages({
    containerID : "itemContainer"
  });

});
</script>



    <ul id="itemContainer">
        <?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                    if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
                        echo '<li>';
                        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                        endwhile;

                    endif;
                    echo '</li>';
                ?>
                </ul>
<!-- pagination -->
<div class="holder"></div>
```

thanks for your help
http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is you are encountering? What is the expected behaviour, and what behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: the pagination of the plugin does not work and you do not take the number of loop entries in the configuration wordpress